# Finding the first shared parent of two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have this DOM structure

```
<body>
    <p>
        Hello
        <i>how <b>are</b> you</i>
        and
        <i>what <b>are <tt>you</tt> going</b> to</i>
        eat tonight?
    </p>
</body>
```

Using jQuery I want to get to know the FIRST shared parent of the

```
<b>are</b>
```

and the

```
<tt>you</tt>
```

From down to top this would be the < p > not the < body > tag.

Any ideas on how to determine the first shared parent utilizing jQuery?

Comment: Most recent common ancestor. Feel like I'm studying genetics or something!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(a).parents().filter(function() { return jQuery.contains(this, b); }).first();
```

If `b` is a selector (as opposed to a DOM element), you can change it to:

```
$(a).closest(':has(b)');
```

This is shorter, but substantially slower.

The order of `a` and `b` is irrelevant; if `b` is closer to the parent, it will be faster.

Comment: This won't work, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/a7hgu/ you have to `return` in a `.filter()` function to get any results.

Comment: @Nick: Fixed; thanks. I suspect that this will be faster than your version, since `contains` calls a native method  (see the jQuery source).  I'm too lazy to check.

Comment: @SLaks - *If* the browser supports it yes, though you can't use a selector directly here so it's a bit messier, depends what you're doing with it (in a loop or not). Just a thought: would be good here if `.closest()` took a set of elements to filter as it goes...

Comment: @Nick: Both of those methods are native DOM methods.  Look more carefully.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes, but one's much more expensive (everything in jQuery is a native dom method...it just depends how deep) for example in Chrome there's a large difference, in Firefox it's much closer.

Comment: @SLaks - `document.documentElement.contains` is the faster of the two...Firefox doesn't have it, which is why the test is so much closer: http://jsperf.com/selector-test-parents

Answer (score 5):

You can combine [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$("b:first").parents().filter($("tt").parents()).first()
//or more generic:
$(elem1).parents().filter($(elem2).parents()).first()
```

This gets *all* shared parents, you can then take the [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)...whatever's needed.

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xS99W/).  Note this is much faster than [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) since we're just comparing 2 DOM element sets, not recursively comparing many.  Also, the resulting set will be in the order going up the document, in this example `<p>` then `<body>`.

Comment: Much better to walk the tree up to the root and trying to find the first match than doing a full search in every subtree.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method

```
$("b:contains('are')").closest(":has(tt:contains('you'))")
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/65hSW/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/65hSW/

Answer (score 0):

Non-jQuery version:

```
var arrayContains = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
    function(arr, val) {
        return arr.indexOf(val) > -1;
    }:

    function(arr, val) {
        var i = arr.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };


function getCommonAncestor(node1, node2) {
    var ancestors = [], n;
    for (n = node1; n; n = n.parentNode) {
        ancestors.push(n);
    }

    for (n = node2; n; n = n.parentNode) {
        if (arrayContains(ancestors, n)) {
            return n;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple non-jquery solution:

```
function sharedParent (elem1, elem2) {
for (; elem1!= null; elem1=elem1.parentNode) {
  for (var e2=elem2; e2!= null; e2=e2.parentNode)
    if (elem1 == e2) return elem1;
  }
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( function(){

  var elem1 = jQuery("#a");
  var elem2 = jQuery("#b");

  var foo1 = elem1.parents().has(elem2).first().attr("tagName");
  var foo2 = elem1.closest(":has(" + elem2.selector + ")").first().attr("tagName");

  alert( foo1 );
  alert( foo2 );


});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ubopu4/edit)